# Can't get webpack dev server connected to ddev host from web container

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, ddev

I try to run an webpack dev server on my ddev web container and get it connected to my host system, so I can reach the URL in my web browser. But I just get an 502: Unresponsive/broken ddev back-end site.

What I want:

- start my ddev container with `ddev start`
- then if I need the webpack dev server I connect via `ddev ssh` to the webcontainer an start the webpack server (`npm run serve`).
- Finally I want to reach the url (https://project.ddev.site.de:8081) in my browser.

Which versions I use:

- nodejs => 16
- webpack-dev-server => 4.3.1
- ddev => 1.18

What I did:

Created a new docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTP_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_PORT}:8025,8080:8080
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTPS_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_HTTPS_PORT}:8025,8081:8080
```

and this is a part of my webpack.config.js:

I created with mkcert two certificates for https.

```js
devServer: {
          static: false,
          // Avoid CORS concerns trying to load things like fonts from the dev server
          headers: {
              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
          hot: true,
          liveReload: false,
          compress: true,
          client: {
              webSocketURL: "auto://0.0.0.0:0/ws",
              logging: 'info',
              progress: true,
              overlay: {
                  warnings: false,
                  errors: true,
              },
          },
          magicHtml: false,
          host: '0.0.0.0',
          port: 8080,
          http2: true,
          https: options.devServer.https,
          devMiddleware: {
              index: false,
              serverSideRender: true,
              publicPath: publicPath,
              writeToDisk: true,
          },
          //watchFiles: [path.join(options.entryPath, '**/*')],
      }
```

I really appreciate for any help.

Comment: Are you able to access it at the http URL (port 8080)? You don't need to create any certs for https - when using HTTPS_EXPOSE, ddev-router does the SSL termination.

Comment: Did you try the tested solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390344/accessing-webpack-dev-server-output-with-specific-port-in-ddev-docker-containe ?

Comment: No, with Port 8080 and over http it is also not reachable. My docker compose setting is from the Link you shared. But I'm not really sure which settings I've to take for webpack. I also tried localhost with Port 8080. Do I have to set a special IP?

Comment: You'll use `http://<projectname>.ddev.site:8080` for your setup. Is that what you're doing? I note you mentioned `https://project.ddev.site.de:8081`, but I don't know how `project.ddev.site.de` is going to get resolved. Please start out just using `project.ddev.site`, which gets resolved in DNS.

Comment: We have a TYPO3 installation and want to do something like this to reach our JS code:
`https://project.ddev.site:8081/typo3conf/ext/distribution/Resources/Public/App/runtime.js`.
But in both ways http or https I get the `502: Unresponsive/broken ddev back-end site`
If I setup the webpack server with host: "project.ddev.site". I get this error from webpack: `address not available 172.18.0.8:8080`

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was missing.
I had to set  `allowedHosts: '.ddev.site'` to my devServer settings
and had to remove `http2` from the settings.

Comment: Please edit your answer to give the complete answer (and more detail about what you were trying to do). Somebody else will want this, and you need to tell them the whole thing. Thanks!