# Webpack Dev Server and DDEV (no backend site available)

Tags: docker, ddev

I followed the accepted answer on this question: [Accessing webpack dev server output with specific port in ddev / docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390344/accessing-webpack-dev-server-output-with-specific-port-in-ddev-docker-containe)

Trying to access the urls at

http://localhost:8080 results in`503: No ddev back-end site available.`

http://`<project>`.ddev.site:8080 results in `502: Unresponsive/broken ddev back-end site.`

Per the answer on the other questions, I added a `docker-compose.devserver.yaml` file with the following contents:

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  web:
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
    - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTP_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_PORT}:8025,8080:8080
    - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_ROUTER_HTTPS_PORT}:80,${DDEV_MAILHOG_HTTPS_PORT}:8025,8081:8080
```

The dev server options are as follows:

```
const devServerOptions = {
    clientLogLevel: 'info', // 'debug',
    contentBase: [
        path.join(__dirname, webPath),
        path.join(__dirname, templatesPath),
    ],
    compress: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host: devServerHost,
    hot: true,
    hotOnly: false,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    https: devServerIsHttps
        ? {
              key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DEVSERVER_KEY),
              cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DEVSERVER_CRT),
              ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.DEVSERVER_CA),
          }
        : false,
    inline: true,
    overlay: true,
    port: devServerPort,
    public: publicPath,
    publicPath: '',
    watchContentBase: true,
    watchOptions: {
        poll: !!parseInt(process.env.DEVSERVER_POLL || 0),
        ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
}
```

Which is pulling the following `.env` vars:

```
DEVSERVER_ENABLED=true
DEVSERVER_HOST=localhost
DEVSERVER_PORT=8080
DEVSERVER_HTTPS=false
```

Assets are attempted to load when I visit `http://<project.ddev.site` at `http://localhost:8080/dist/styles/main.min.css` for instance and result in the 503 error mentioned about where there's no backend ddev site available.

If I remove the `docker-compose` file mentioned above and instead add to the `.ddev/config.yaml` file:

```
web_extra_exposed_ports:
  - name: devserver
    container_port: 8080
    http_port: 8080
    https_port: 8081
```

Without running my `yarn dev` (`cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --stats=minimal --progress`) command and then running `ddev exec curl localhost:8080`, I receive `connection refused`.

After running `yarn dev`, I receive the `index.html` file of my apps main entry point. (This is a Craft CMS app, so it's pulling the index.html in the templates. Pulls Twig comments too, so it's outputting the actual file contents)

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to make sure it works successfully inside the container. `ddev exec curl localhost:8080` and see if you get the results you expect.  You don't say how you're launching the daemon; you may want to use web_extra_daemons and web_extra_exposed_ports, which is probably easier than what you're doing, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#running-extra-daemons-in-the-web-container

Comment: @rfay thank you for your reply. I'd edited my question to include a few more tests. I did not realize I needed to launch any daemon. I do not have any special config for that. Not sure what I'd add. Sorry for my ignorance here.

Comment: And does `ddev exec curl localhost:8080` show you the output you expect? If not, you'll get the "broken back-end side" because the server you want to be running on port 8080 isn't running.

Comment: @rfay after taking a break and coming back, I noticed if I do the `ddev exec curl localhost:8080/dist/styles/style.css` command, it spits out the CSS I expect. So the dev server is working. However, in the browser, this file is not accessible. The console show CONNECTION REFUSED and navigating to the file give the "Refused to connect" error.

Comment: noting that i am using WSL2. If I run just `curl localhost:8080` I do get connection refused. running curl inside DDEV gives me the correct response.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue. Thank you for your help in debugging. I will write an answer later in case it helps someone in the future.

Comment: It's still waiting for your answer @good_afternoon.

Comment: sorry about that, @rfay. Posted.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this issue may not work for everyone.

One thing I found is that I had to have the dev server accessible via a DDEV url, i.e `<project-name>.ddev.site` instead of localhost.

Next, I was having issues with ports. This may vary for other people, but I first tried ports 1339, 8080, 8000, with no luck. It wasn't until I used 9000 that I had luck.

For exposed ports in DDEV, I did not need to create a new `docker-compose` file, but rather use the `web_extra_exposed_ports` option in the `config.yaml` file in the `.ddev` folder.

```
web_extra_exposed_ports:
  - name: devserver
    container_port: 9000
    http_port: 9000
    https_port: 9001
```

Note: you need the `https_port` even if you do not plan on using https.

Finally, in my `package.json` where the command is created to run the webpack dev server, I needed to add the option `--host=0.0.0.0`

And of course, make sure you start the webpack dev server before navigating to your site.

Comment: Your port problem may mean either that you have an overactive firewall or that you have completing processes on the other ports you tried.

Comment: Adding `--host=0.0.0.0` and `--httpPort=9000` solved for me for a serverless offline server.